# Maven ignores a repository

Tags: maven, profile, repository

I'm unable to get Maven download an artifact

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.test-jsf</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-mock</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.9</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

This dependency isn't in the Maven Central. I've added the proper repository to my settings.

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>barbucha</id>
    </profile>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>jboss</id>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <url>http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>jboss-plug</id>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <url>http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
</profiles>
```

Then I build things using the `barbucha` profile. However maven doesn't use the JBoss repository at all. It tries to get the missing dependency from Central instead. It tries to download the dependency twice and then fails:

```
[INFO] Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jboss/test-jsf/jsf-mock/1.1.9/jsf-mock-1.1.9.pom
[WARNING] The POM for org.jboss.test-jsf:jsf-mock:jar:1.1.9 is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO] Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jboss/test-jsf/jsf-mock/1.1.9/jsf-mock-1.1.9.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project: Could not resolve dependencies for project: Could not find artifact org.jboss.test-jsf:jsf-mock:jar:1.1.9 in central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) -> [Help 1]
```

The behavior is very strange and sadly critical to me. I googled a long time, but nothing found, what can cause the problem. The only reason can be the profile if not activated. But that isn't my case.

Answer (score 5):

Oh, it was so simple - my settings are just malformed:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>barbucha</id>
    </profile> <<< this must be at the end (at <!-- #1 --->)
    <repositories>
    ... <!-- this part must be inside of profile -->
    </pluginRepositories>
    <!-- #1 --->
</profiles>
```

I apologize. (Hopefully it may help to someone.)